# JavaFX Getting MySQLSyntaxErrorException at some datas only

Tags: mysql, javafx, syntax-error, javafx-8, mysql-error-1064

i am trying to change some datas to mysql , and for some items or id's(PK) it works fine , but for 2 or 3 of them i get MySQLSyntaxErrorException.

Here's the code:

```
@FXML
    public void azhurnoPaisjen() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/*****";
        String user = "******";
        String pass = "******";
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pass);
        PreparedStatement ptmt;
        double pagesa = Double.parseDouble(qmimi.getText()) + Double.parseDouble(puneDore.getText());
        System.out.println(pagesa);
        String query = "update paisjettable set prodhuesi='"+ prodhuesi.getText() +"' , modeli='"+ modeli.getText() +"' , paisja='"+ paisja.getText() +"' , pjesa='"+ pjesa.getText() +"' , qmimi='"+ Double.parseDouble(qmimi.getText()) +"' , punedore='"+ Double.parseDouble(puneDore.getText()) +"' , pagesa='"+ pagesa +"' , sasia='"+ Integer.parseInt(sasia.getText()) +"' , infoshtese='"+ info.getText() +"'  where id='"+ id +"'";
        ptmt = connect.prepareStatement(query);
        ptmt.executeUpdate();  // THIS IS LINE 98

        ptmt.close();
        connect.close();
        PaisjetController.azhurnoPaisjen.close();
    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Alumin'  where id='18'' at line 1
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1631)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:1723)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.execSQL(Connection.java:3283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1332)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1604)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1519)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1504)
    at automekanikadmin.AzhurnoPaisjenController.azhurnoPaisjen(AzhurnoPaisjenController.java:98)
    ... 110 more
```

p.s " 17' Alumin " is the text from info(TextArea)

Comment: Print out all your Values that you use in your query and check what they are saying

Comment: And make sure you are not entering the ' Character into your input fields

Comment: `'18''` isnt a valid string. This kind of things tend to happen, if you attempt to create the query by concatenating everything... Use a `PreparedStatement` to insert the variable values instead. Note that this kind of query creation is also an serious security issue (sql injection). http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Yep Thank you i get it now , the problem is that in the textField i wirte ' character

Comment: First note, this has nothing to do with javafx. It is just a simple MySQL error. Second, you should use ?-placeholders in a PreparedStatement! Last, first try the SQL update directly (using MySQL CLI). That makes debugging (and development) MUCH more efficient!

Comment: See https://xkcd.com/327/ ...